# SQL Server 2008 "issues"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssms

There is *something* wrong with my installation of SQL Server that I can't put my finger on, which is why the vague title of this post.

As an example, I was trying to open an MDF file that is part of an example solution from MSDN for DataGrid templates, and got the following error.

[image]

The info about my install from SQL Server Management Studio is below.

Can someone help me solve the problem I'm having opening the MDF file? Is this a symptom of my install in general, as I suspect? If so, can you suggest how to resolve the install?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.2531.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.0.6002.18005
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework    2.0.50727.4216
Operating System    6.0.6002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is version 612 which is actually SQL Server *2005* (SELECT @@VERSION to verify this) and the file your attaching is 622 which is SQL Server *2008*, you cannot attach an mdf sourced from a newer version of SQL server.

Comment: This makes sense, but how do I get up to 2008 then? I made that a [separate question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154445/sqlserver-2008-instance)