# SQL Server 2008 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 and the Management Studio installed on my machine, but I apparently only have an instance of 2005 running on it.

SQL Server 2008 Mgt Studio Info

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.2531.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.0.6002.18005
- Microsoft MSXML 3.0 5.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
- Microsoft .NET Framework    2.0.50727.4216
- Operating System    6.0.6002

How do I either upgrade that instance to 2008 or create a new instance?

Comment: You might have **multiple instances** of SQL Server installed on your machine - you just need to connect to the **correct one**. Check your list of services - do you see a `MSSQLSERVER` service? Is there another one that sorta looks similar? That might be your second instance....

Comment: What have you tried? what failures are you seeing? Without more info, the answer is "Insert the SQL 2008 DVD, run the installer, select the instance to upgrade."

Comment: @JamieF. I tried upgrading from the disk two years ago, and I don't know where it is anymore. I appreciate that that this seems like a lame question to you, or if it looks like I haven't researched this properly, but I'm doing the best I can here without that dvd.

Comment: And for the record, I wasn't the downvote, although I can see why. You'll need to have SQL Server install media to upgrade a 2005 instance.

Comment: @JamieF. I don't care about the points per se, and I appreciate 'constructive' criticism as much as you do. If you don't know a topic, you don't know it, so you have to start somewhere until you do. I thought learning was at least part of the point of SO. A downvote without any explanation doesn't seem productive to me in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your other post, you should be fine with the express edition (found here).

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx